# High dimensional data stream summarization and processing

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, anomaly-detection, dimensionality-reduction, data-stream-mining

Can anyone recommend a method for summarizing and processing high dimensional data streams efficiently and effectively for anomaly detection?

In fact, I investigated the different methods for data stream summarization (sampling, histograms, sketches, wavelets, sliding windows) and am confused about the choice. In fact, I noticed that sampling and sliding windows are general purpose and keep the raw data, while the others are task-specific and make transformations to the data.

I am interested in the first case but it may be more consuming.

Comment: Summarizing and processing is domain specific. What is your domain?